# overflow:hidden doesn't expand a div as expected

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div id="row" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="logged_in_mainboxes" style="margin: auto; width: 700px;overflow: hidden; ">
        <h3>Band profiles:</h3>


        <div class="fish" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%;">
            asdasd
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I have is that overflow:hidden doesn't seem to work. The logged_in_mainboxes-div is not expanded with the fish-div.

Comment: Actually you have to set the parent div named: "logged_in_mainboxes" as relative, otherwise it will not expanded.

Check my answer and let me know is it okey for you or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

**Modified HTML:**

```
<div id="row" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="logged_in_mainboxes">
        <h3>Band profiles:</h3>
        <div class="fish">
            asdasd
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The Modified CSS is given below:**

```
<style>
.fish{ 
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    bottom: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.logged_in_mainboxes{
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: @AMACB, I explain it in comment. Please check.